# О значении слова "славист"

Tags: лексика

**Из Интернета:** "С этим словом (**речь идет о глаголе "зоревать"**) не всё просто, поскольку периодически проводится незаметное для многих носителей "реформирование" речи и языка, **нам же, славистам, приходится за этими изменениями следить"**.

Действительно, слависты без дела не сидят, но о каких славистах в этой фразе идет речь?

Из словаря: **СЛАВИСТ**, -а; м. Специалист по славяноведению. Съезд славистов. Получить консультацию слависта. **СЛАВЯНОВЕДЕНИЕ**,  Совокупность наук, изучающих историю, литературу, язык, фольклор, этнографию и т.д., а также памятники материальной и духовной культуры славян.

Верно ли в данном случае употреблено это слово?

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2215490-zarevat-ili-zorevat-kak-pishetsja.html#reply2313957

Answer (score 2):

```
  Верно ли в данном случае употреблено это слово?
```

А в чём сомнение?

До 1870-х годов основными областями интереса славистов  были лингвистика и филология. Слависты сосредотачивали своё внимание на изучении памятников славянской письменности, на истории становления славянских народов, развитии национальных языков и литератур. Русским языком занимались русисты (ветвь славистов). Чередование зар/зор - историческое, современными фонетическими законами не объясняется, может быть объяснено с точки зрения фонетики той эпохи, существования долгих и кратких гласных, затем редуцированных гласных, т. е. исторически.

И с отменой исключений зоревать, зорянка далеко не все слависты согласились, потому что теряется исконный смысл слов, забывается то, что было слово зОря - сполохи, о связи с другими русскими словами. Так что это тематика чисто русистов-славистов, хотя их можно назвать и лингвистами, конечно, но это очень широко, слависты - более точно, в других славянских языках исторические чередования остались и в современности.

Comment: Людмила, но почему изменения в русской орфографии отслеживают слависты, а не филологи или русисты. Может быть, в данном тексте это синонимы? И могут ли эти слова заменять друг друга. Сравнить: "Ко мне приходили не только слависты и филологи" (Василий Аксенов). "Слависты и русисты ― народ особый. Это весьма отчаянные и самоотверженные люди ― ведь всегда неизвестно, чего с Востока ожидать?" (Михаил Гиголашвили).

Comment: Это синонимы.Филолог -самое широкое понятие, он занимается изучением культуры народов        ( язык, литература). русист - специалист в области русской филологии, славист - специалист в области славянской филологии. Так что  русист - и филолог, и славист; славист - и филолог, и в какой-то мере русист. Филолог должен быть компетентен и в русистике, и в славистике, и в полонистике, и в др.

Answer (score 0):

Полный ЦСС  в статье (на стр. 613) слова СЛАВА полагает корнем его СЛЫТЬ: называться, именоваться, быть известным. И далее: «Отсюда происходит и *слово*, и *слух*, и *слава*; так что в древности иногда одно из этих слов заменяло другое, например *словый* употреблялось вместо *славый*».

Статья эта также ссылается на разные источники, где СЛАВА напрямую связывается с мнением, суждением, учением, верой.

Верно ли в данном случае употреблено это слово? Безусловно. Славист изучает славянскую словесность.

Answer (score 0):

> Верно ли в данном случае употреблено это слово?

А шут его знает. Или, вернее, автор. Если он отнес себя к славистам, то почему не верно? Надо его спросить, о каких славистах идет речь.

Славист - специалист по славяноведению, славистике.

СЛАВЯНОВЕДЕНИЕ, -я; ср. Совокупность наук, изучающих историю, литературу, язык, фольклор, этнографию и т.д., а также памятники материальной и духовной культуры славян; славистика.

Язык, как минимум, сюда входит. Т.е. понятие "филолог-славист" вполне возможно по таким определениям. Автор, судя по всему, именно таких славистов, филологических, и имел ввиду. А почему нет?!

Увидела.

> Людмила, но почему изменения в русской орфографии отслеживают
>   слависты, а не филологи или русисты.

А, вон вы о чем... Это немного другое. Да, в таком понимании "славист" это слишком широко, это не синоним русиста, а его гипероним (частичный). Но не думаю, что в разговорной речи такие моменты могут вызывать непонимание. Во всяком случае, я даже не подумала о какой-то подмене понятия, прочитав цитируемое вами сообщение. Думаю, если не копать глубоко русиста вполне допустимо назвать славистом.

Comment: Всё-таки я думаю, что  не стоит смешивать эти понятия даже в разговорных ситуациях: СЛАВИСТ – это специалист по славянской культуре, причем бывают филологи-слависты, этнологи-слависты  и языковеды-слависты, и специализируются они по конкретным славянским языкам. Конечно,  слависты изучают русский язык, но он необязательно является для них основным. Поэтому русским языком должны заниматься выпускники филологических факультетов российских вузов по специальности «русский язык и литература», к общей славистике эта специальность  прямого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Sibylla это всё очень субъективно. У меня внутреннего протеста не вызвало. Людмила вон вообще видит в них полный синонимы. Не вижу предмета для серьезного спора.